# To produce a pure statically linked binary, is it still necessary to compile with -tags netgo in Go 1.5+?

Tags: go, static-linking

I'm trying to create a pure statically linked binary to run in a minimal Docker container. Prior to Go 1.5, I was building them like this:

```
go build -a -tags netgo -installsuffix netgo myfile.go
```

I understand that C has been stripped out of the Go compiler in version 1.5. Is it still necessary to build with `-tags` and `-installsuffix`?

Answer (score 9):

https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#net

> The DNS resolver in the net package has almost always used cgo to
>   access the system interface. A change in Go 1.5 means that on most
>   Unix systems DNS resolution will no longer require cgo, which
>   simplifies execution on those platforms. Now, if the system's
>   networking configuration permits, the native Go resolver will suffice.
>   The important effect of this change is that each DNS resolution
>   occupies a goroutine rather than a thread, so a program with multiple
>   outstanding DNS requests will consume fewer operating system
>   resources.
>
> The decision of how to run the resolver applies at run time, not build
>   time. **The netgo build tag that has been used to enforce the use of the
>   Go resolver is no longer necessary**, although it still works. A new
>   netcgo build tag forces the use of the cgo resolver at build time. To
>   force cgo resolution at run time set GODEBUG=netdns=cgo in the
>   environment. More debug options are documented here.
>
> This change applies to Unix systems only. Windows, Mac OS X, and Plan
>   9 systems behave as before.

So no.